# C# - get rstp from video programmatically

Tags: c#, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I'm building a program Watch Online. I am looking for a way to get RSTP address in C #.

I tried to find solutions on Google and various forums, but have not found a solution.

The problem is I do not know how to get RSTP URL of a video, and I dont know of a function like

this in C #.

Comment: Where are these videos coming from? Don't really understand, what you try to do.

Comment: i try to see video from my program that i build . 
and this videoo come from this site : http://www.mapsutim.co.il/files/tv22-1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want RTSP URL? At site that you've mentioned video goes over flash and as a rule it uses RTMP but not RTSP. Don't think it's possible to do in C# in a simple way, the easiest will be putting URL manually, you could get it via Wireshark with rtmpt filtering (Checkout Handshake C2 packet).

Comment: yes , you correct !! but i dond know how to do it .